# Putting Two Consecutive Lines into One Line with Perl / AWK

Tags: linux, perl, unix, text, awk

I have a data like below:

```
abcd
join abcd
efgh
join efgh
```

I want to join the two consecutive pair into one line.
Resulting:

```
abcd join abcd
efgh join efgh
```

How can I do it in Perl/AWK?

Comment: Your output changed with your edit -- the first did not have extra space and the second does have extra space. Also, is the `join` itself explicit in the data or is that just an unfortunate coincidence?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$ sed 'N;s/\n/ /' input.txt
abcd join abcd
efgh join efgh
```

Comment: I like this one better than mine.

Comment: How does this work? I can see from sed manual that N command appends input to pattern space and ; seems to be a command-separator. How is the print happening only every other line?

Comment: Can't understand how it works, can you explain it? :)

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way is:

```
paste - - < FILE
```

This joins using a space instead of a tab:

```
paste -d" " - - < FILE
```

Comment: Good, except that inserts tabs; `paste -d" " - -` matches the desired output better.  And you don't need the `cat` pipe, just `paste -d" " - - < FILE`

Comment: @Mike Reed, I was about to say exactly the same thing. I fixed it for Andrey Yazu.

Comment: Yes, I usually process the result with awk so I forgot about tab. Thank you for fixing.

Answer (score 4):

Perl:

```
perl -pe's/\n/ / if $. % 2' file
```

---

Golf challenge: Shorten the above by 5 chars.

Golf challenge solution:

```
perl -pe'$.%2&&s/
/ /' file
```

Comment: Nice and concise; I like it - almost as much as the sed. :)

Comment: @ikegami: good to see you here! It's been a long time since our time in PM :-)

Comment: Thanks. I managed to shorten for 4 char; I had in mind your solution too, but I thought it's not anymore a one-liner.

Comment: I don't think the one-char savings you get by replacing `\n` with a literal newline is useful. :)  But good golfing, @ikegami!

Comment: @sid_com, good catch then :) [Who said one-liner? And does it really stop being a one-liner if it can be put into virtually any shell command where the truly one-line version can be placed?]

Answer (score 3):

```
cat input | paste -sd' \n'
```

Paste alternates between delimiters if a list is given.

Answer (score 2):

My first instinct:

```
perl -lne 'if ($. % 2) { $last = $_; } else { print "$last $_" }'
```

Somewhat more concise version inspired by @kev's sed solution:

```
perl -lpe '$_ .= " " . <>; chomp'
```

But I think sed wins this round.

Comment: `-a` is useless here! See also my answer for a concise Perl solution

Comment: Yeah, the '-a' was copypasta from another solution I had just been working on with columns.  Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{getline a; printf "%-s\n", $0 " " a}' file
```

Comment: Shorter: `awk '{getline a; print $0, a}' file`