# How to list network interfaces that are configured with IP with the interface name

Tags: awk, sed, grep, ifconfig

I am looking for a command line to show the interfaces and the ip associated with the interface. I run the command ifconfig -a | grep -inet .. but I need to print the interface also . How can I also print the interface name?

Command

```
ifconfig -a | grep inet
```

Input

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:A8:F0:2D:B3:98
          inet addr:10.33.211.67  Bcast:10.33.211.79      
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8C:DC:D4:AD:A6:EF
          inet addr:64.15.238.227  Bcast:64.15.238.239  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3532763832 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

eth8      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:A8:F0:2D:B3:9A
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3532763832 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
```

Desired output

```
eth1    inet addr:10.33.211.67  Bcast:10.33.211.79 Mask:255.255.255.240
eth2    inet addr:64.15.238.227 Bcast:64.15.238.239  Mask:255.255.255.240
eth8    ----------  blank because it has not been configured
```

Comment: Where is the Mask supposed to come from ?

Comment: I do not have access to dev/net not logged in as root - also mask comes from the command above ifconfig -a | grep inet -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following `sed` pipeline:

```
ifconfig -a | sed -n -e 's/^\([[:alnum:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\).*$/\1/p' -e 's/^[[:space:]]\+\(inet .*\)$/\1/p' | sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
```

The first `sed` command selects lines that start with an interface name or a bunch of spaces followed by `inet`. The second one removes every other newline from the result based on [Putting Two Consecutive Lines into One Line with Perl / AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220348/putting-two-consecutive-lines-into-one-line-with-perl-awk). Output will be:

```
eth1       inet addr:10.33.211.67  Bcast:10.33.211.79      
eth2       inet addr:64.15.238.227  Bcast:64.15.238.239  
eth8
```

Comment: that's really s(l)ick ;-)