# Delete line char using sed when not matching a pattern

Tags: sed, grep

After my grep, I generated a file which has data as key and count but on separate lines:

```
$Value, "Some", $233kS
:2343
$AnotherCount, JunkValue
:38585
YetAnother, Nothing
:38484
```

I want a file like:

```
$Value, "Some", $233kS:2343
$AnotherCount, JunkValue:38585
YetAnother, Nothing:38484
```

The count pattern is fixed, it is always of form :[0-9]*
Is it possible using `sed` or any single line command?

I looked at [replace line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed) but I want only when the count pattern is not matched.

I am interested in solution that can work for extended problem:

```
$Value, "Some", $233kS
$AnotherCount, JunkValue
:38585
YetAnother, Nothing
:38484
```

Should output:

```
$Value, "Some", $233kS$AnotherCount, JunkValue:38585
YetAnother, Nothing:38484
```

Basically, all the lines not matching the pattern should not have end line char.

Comment: `when the count pattern is not matched` No? It looks you want to match it and remove a newline in front of it. `s/\n\(:[0-9]*\)/\1/g`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I join pairs of consecutive lines in a large file (1 million lines) using vim, sed, or another similar tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545538/how-do-i-join-pairs-of-consecutive-lines-in-a-large-file-1-million-lines-using)

Comment: Also [Putting Two Consecutive Lines into One Line with Perl / AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10220348/5291015)

Comment: Another possibility is to use `awk` or similar instead of your previous `grep` step, for that we'd need original sample and explanation of the grep command you used to get current output

Comment: I agree that `Putting 2 lines..` or `joining pair of lines ` can solve my problem but I am interested in know who can I selectively remove any end line character to merge the next line with it. (Based on pattern matching)

Comment: *knowing how [ sorry for the typo ]

Comment: And realize that `awk` allows you to `grep` AND logicially test lines and manipulate them all in one language and process. `awk '/MatchThis/{if (test > that) {print "the other $NF"} else {print "not matched"}}' file` is the general idea. See [Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) . Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of these might help you out:

```
$ awk '!(FNR%2){ print b $0 }{b=$0}' file
$ paste -sd "\0\n" file
```

Both of these lines assume that the odd lines need to be concatenated with the even lines

**note:** according to [POSIX `paste`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html#tag_20_89_04) "\0" is considered an empty string, not the <null>-character

Comment: Both these work for my original problem. Can you please see the extended problem?

Comment: @impossible that'd be `awk '{ORS = /^:[0-9]/ ? "\n" : ""} 1'` I'm sure there's a duplicate somewhere...